# Numpy: Create shallow-copied array of Python objects

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of `namedtuple` objects, which I'd like to put into a `numpy` array so I can use its convenient index assignment operations. Consider an input like so,

```
In [3]: Point = namedtuple("Point", ["x", "y"])
In [4]: x_lst = [Point(1, 2), Point(3, 4)]
```

By default, numpy will create 2D arrays out of its input,

```
In [5]: numpy.array(x_lst)
Out[5]:
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [6]: numpy.array(x_lst).shape
Out[6]: (2, 2)
```

One can suppress this to an extent with the records type, but it's still doing some type manipulation of its input (casting each element to a regular tuple, in this case),

```
In [7]: numpy.core.records.array(x_lst)
Out[7]:
rec.array([(1, 2), (3, 4)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8')])
```

I've managed to work around the issue like so,

```
In [8]: result = numpy.full((2,), None, dtype=object)
In [9]: result[:] = x_lst

In [10]: type(result[0])
Out[10]: __main__.Point
```

but this seems less than elegant. Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

I would use

```
In [1152]: xx=np.empty((2,),dtype=object)
In [1153]: xx[:] = x_lst
In [1154]: xx
Out[1154]: array([Point(x=1, y=2), Point(x=3, y=4)], dtype=object)
```

But yes, it is essentially the same thing as your solution.

I have observed in other SO questions that creating object arrays usually requires some trickery.  `np.array()` by default tries to create the highest dimensional numeric array that it can from the data.  Your namedtuple object is iterable (that's one of its features), `[i for i in Point(1,2)]`, so to `np.array` `x_lst` looks just like a list of tuples: `[(1,2),(3,4)]`.

Creating an empty object array, and filling it with `[:]` seems to be simplest solution.

Since the points are iterable, various operations on that array may be unpredictable.  For example:

```
In [1198]: xx.sum()
Out[1198]: (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

If the class is not iterable, creating a object array is simpler:

```
In [1179]: class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args=args
   ......:         

In [1180]: yy=np.array([MyObject(1,2),MyObject(1,2,3)])

In [1181]: yy
Out[1181]: 
array([<__main__.MyObject object at 0xb18e0a8c>,
       <__main__.MyObject object at 0xb18e0aac>], dtype=object)

In [1182]: yy[0].args
Out[1182]: (1, 2)
```

Same for lists or tuples with varying sizes, which it can't force into a 2d array:

```
In [1183]: np.array([(1,2),(1,2,3)])
Out[1183]: array([(1, 2), (1, 2, 3)], dtype=object)
```

In either of these, the elements could be replaced, after creation, with your points.